# Any equivalent to virtualenvwrapper's hook scripts in conda?

Tags: virtualenvwrapper, anaconda

With [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#variable-virtualenvwrapper-hook-dir), one can install "hooks" that can be run, say, after a virtualenv is activated.
I suspect not, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: We should work on a pull request or create a `condawrapper` similar to `virtualenvwrapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there currently isn't such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch conda's `activate` script directly. But your changes will be overwritten whenever you update conda.  Here's an example that changes to a directory in your $HOME based on the environment name:

```
echo 'cd "$HOME/code/$1"' >> "$(which activate)"
```

Unfortunately this will only work if you use the old-school activate command:
`source activate project_name` rather than `conda activate project_name`